# Need help starting a Parsing Code Generator for C++

Tags: c++, parsing, tree, generator

So I'm working through my CS degree and currently taking a Programming Language concept class. The first assignment is to create a program that generates a random syntactically correct but does not have to be semantically correct. This assignment came after going over the BNF gramner. I have never even seen a program that creates a parse tree or uses one. I'm going from 0 to 4000 with this assignment and to be honest doubting my abilities a little. I'm not looking for a free ride but Just some help even starting the program. I'm not even sure what the Main program is suppose to look like or how it would work. Any guides or references for C++ parse programs would be great. Or some sample source code of a parser in c++.

This is the assignment...

The purpose of this exercise is to write a syntax generator for a subset of the C++ programming
language that will write “random” C++ programs to a file. By writing these random syntactically
correct programs, you will further develop your understanding of the difference between syntax
and semantics.

Consider the following set of productions that define a subset of the C++ programming
language:

(prog) ::= "int main() { (stat_list) return 0; }"

(stat_list) ::= (stat)
            | (stat_list) (stat)

(stat)      ::= (cmpd_stat)
            | (if_stat)
            | (iter_stat)
            | (assgn_stat)
            | (decl_stat)

The above in only a few of the 16 production rules for the assignment.

Problem 1.​ Write a program in C, C++, C#, Java, or Python (your choice) that starts with the
root non-terminal  and generates a random syntactically correct C++ program using the
productions defined above. You should follow the examples we saw in class where we expand
non-terminals recursively until we obtain a sentence consisting of terminal tokens only. In the
case where a production contains more than one expansion (i.e., right-hand-side expressions),
your program should select one randomly (preferably with non-uniform weighting based on
which expansions are more likely to occur in C++). Your program should write the random C++
code to an output file.

I'm have to use C++ for the assignment because that is the only language that I how after taking the intro classes to CS classes.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Write a "Lexer" class that transforms the input string into tokens. Write a "Parser" class with a function for each grammar rule. Use the magic of recursion.

Comment: You need to research the internet for "c++ parse tree example".

Comment: Did your instructor discuss parse trees?  Did you miss a lecture or two?  Talk with your instructor about parse trees.

Comment: Did you complete the data structures class before taking this class?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: There is no data structures class before this one. And no I didn't miss any lectures, the topic that we are going over is syntax and semantics. Which is why I noted that it felt like going 0-4000. This exercise is well over my head right now which is why I'm asking for help. I have researched on the net for parse tree examples in C++ but not having much luck. Wish people wouldn't down vote for asking for help.

Comment: "Can someone help me?"  The Problem 1 statement you provided *is* the help you need; it clearly describes a solution you should be able to implement.  The instructor even says he showed you in class how to *expand non-terminals recursively* (which is the essence of the problem solution); this is an operation on strings of tokens and is actually pretty easy.    So, either he's a poor teacher and didn't show you well, or it didn't stick in your brain.  Either way, you have to get this or you miss the whole point of parsing.   Go ask him for help in understanding that idea.

Comment: .... usually when this kind of thing is taught, you are shown how to manually expand nonterminals using grammar rules until the result matches in the input string.  And you tend to do it on paper to record how the expansions fill out to do the match.  I assume you did that in class, and on paper by yourself.  He's asking you automate that process, but to pick a random terminal token when you have a choice rather than matching a specific input.

Answer (score 1):

The key here is

> You should follow the examples we saw in class where we expand non-terminals recursively until we obtain a sentence consisting of terminal tokens only.

You did see those examples in class, right? If not, here's an example using a grammar for a somewhat natural language based on English. I use a convention similar to the one you seem to be using, where terminals (that is, actual output) is inside quotes (`"fox"`) while the names of non-terminals (types of phrases) are in parentheses (`(noun phrase)`). If you've never taken an English grammar course, you might want to take a glance at this [parts of speech list](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/word-classes-or-parts-of-speech).

Rules

```
(sentence) ::= (noun phrase) (verb phrase)
(noun phrase) ::= (pronoun) | (determiner) (noun)
(verb phrase) ::= (intransitive verb) | (transitive verb) (noun phrase)

(determiner) ::= "a" | "the"
(pronoun)    ::= "I" | "you"
(noun)       ::= "bug" | "cloud"
(intransitive verb) ::= "thought" | "procrastinated"
(transitive verb)   ::= "followed" | "liked"
```

I left out adjectives, adverbs, singular/plural agreement and a bunch of other interesting stuff. But we can generate a few sentences.

We start with

```
(sentence)
```

That can only be substituted with

```
(noun phrase) (verb phrase)
```

There are two possible `(noun phrase)` substitutions. Coin flip is tails, so we substitute `(determiner) (noun)`:

```
(determiner) (noun) (verb phrase)
```

There are two possible `(determiner)` substitutions. Coin flip is tails again, so we substitute "the"

```
"the" (noun) (verb phrase)
```

OK, I'm going to condense this. At each step, we do a substitution for the first remaining non-terminal (parenthesized name, remember). We can write out the entire derivation (that's what it's called) in two columns: What we have so far, and the substitution we're going to apply (always to the first unexpanded non-terminal). So each line starts with the result of the substitution of the previous line:

```
(sentence)                                     | (sentence) ::= (noun phrase) (verb phrase)
(noun phrase) (verb phrase)                    | (noun phrase) ::= (determiner) (noun) 
(determiner) (noun) (verb phrase)              | (determiner) ::= "the"   
"the" (noun) (verb phrase)                     | (noun) ::= "cloud"       
"the" "cloud" (verb phrase)                    | (verb phrase) ::= (transitive verb) (noun phrase)
"the" "cloud" (transitive verb) (noun phrase)  | (transitive verb) ::= "followed" 
"the" "cloud" "followed" (noun phrase)         | (noun phrase) ::= (determiner) (noun)
"the" "cloud" "followed" (determiner) (noun)   | (determiner) ::= "the"   
"the" "cloud" "followed" "the" (noun)          | (noun) ::= "bug"
"the" "cloud" "followed" "the" "bug"
```

Here's another one:

```
(sentence)                                 | (sentence) ::= (noun phrase) (verb phrase)
(noun phrase) (verb phrase)                | (noun phrase) ::= (determiner) (noun)
(determiner) (noun) (verb phrase)          | (determiner) ::= "a"
"a" (noun) (verb phrase)                   | (noun) ::= "bug"
"a" "bug" (verb phrase)                    | (verb phrase) ::= (transitive verb) (noun phrase)
"a" "bug" (transitive verb) (noun phrase)  | (transitive verb) ::= "liked" 
"a" "bug" "liked" (noun phrase)            | (noun phrase) ::= (pronoun)
"a" "bug" "liked" (pronoun)                | (pronoun) ::= "you"
"a" "bug" "liked" "you"
```

(It's about 20 lines of code, and the only data structures are the grammar, a map of strings to vectors of vectors of strings, and two vectors of strings containing the intermediate result.)